# Understanding code coverage report in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am running few unit tests in php and generated the code coverage report as:

```
phpunit --coverage-text ./report testBlahBlah.php
```

Result is as follows:

```
 Summary:
 Classes: 0.00%(0/1)
 Methods : 55.56% (10/18)
 Lines 56.58% (43/76)

Class BlahBlah
Methods: 77.78(14/18) Lines 56.58 %(43/76)
```

I want to understand the meaning of this report. Can anybody throw some light on this. Which class is being talked here, because anyways report for each class under test also comes. Why Methods percentage is different in Summary and code class, as only one class exists. Can anybody understand this.

Comment: I have edited the question, added report for class under test too.

Answer (score 0):

Well php unit tests all the involved classes in the test project. Of all the lines (of all classes) together, 8 are covered.

If 100% of the lines of a method are covered, then that method is covered. It appears that those eight lines are concentrated in just one method.

And if 100% of the lines of a class are covered. That class is covered as well. Since your test project involves only one class, and 8/76 are covered. That class is not covered.

A coverage report is in most cases a summary when testing a large library (with hundreds of classes). The report only summarizes the tests so one can decide if additional tests are necessary.

Comment: I believe it actually requires 100% coverage of a class/method to count it covered.

Comment: @npfedwards: well as far as I know you can set a parameter. Furthermore sometimes 100% is even impossible (or hard) to achieve.

Comment: Ah I must just have come across a default at 100%. I think 100% should be what we are aiming for.